# Proper way to handle NULL (empty) values for user-defined table types passed as params to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, user-defined-type, query-performance

My stored procedures accepts table value parameters for querying data.

Usually those are custom user-defined table types for where clause. Business logic of stored procedures push me to these `@tables` be optional.

Sometimes there is data inside `@table`, sometimes there is not.

Here is way how I handle these

```
select 
     ... etc
from tebel ...
    ...etc
where 
     (table1.id in (select id from @UserDefinedTableTypeParam ) or (select count(*) from @UserDefinedTableTypeParam ) = 0)
     and (table2.id = @OtherIntParam or @OtherIntParam = 0)
```

I see that my code is ugly but I do not know is there better way to avoid  using count(*) inside subquery of where clause ?

My focus is to keep performance of my T-SQL code at respectable level.
Does this `@UserDefinedTableTypeParam` confusing SQL execution plans and the query optimizer?

Comment: I use an outer join on optional table-valued parameters like this when the desired result is to filter by the table values or not filter at all. For the int parameter, you could use something like `table2.id = isnull(@OtherIntParam, table2.id)` (assuming a default of null for the param).

Comment: As dartonw states, an outer join will be much cleaner and most likely perform better.  Once you declare the table variable, you are not dealing with a null value anymore, but rather an empty temporary table, for all intents and purposes.